# I need help with verilog code, I am in trouble?

Tags: verilog, computer-architecture, vlsi, system-verilog, alu

I am basically setting different control signals for the ALU to perform operations in verilog. But I have tried all possible ways of writing what I want but in vain, can you help me out. How should I set these control signals at particular 3 bit alu states;

This is my code, i have all possible assignments;
(sorry, its inverteed and i don't know how to rotate it because the website i upload pictures on automatically rotated it this way)

Initial declarations;

```
input [1:0] op, src, srl, dst_ram_mux, dst_q_mux;
input inv_s, inv_r, sel, dst_ram_en, dst_qen, dst_y, cin, reg_wr, cp;

 95 always @(i[5] or i[4] or i[3])
 96 begin
 97 if( i[5]==0  && i[4] == 0 && i[3] == 0)         // this is add   S+R
 98 begin
 99      cin <= 0;
 100     assign sel = 0;
 101     inv_s <= 0;
 102     assign inv_r = i[5] & i[4] & i[3];
 103     op[1] = i[5] & i[4] & i[3];                                        
 104     op[0] = 0;
 105 end
```

The 'end' for the always is way below at line 327, not seen here

The errors for all assignments;

[image]

Comment: Please, for the love of all you hold holy, get rid of the pictures and *copy and paste* your code (remembering to indent it 4 characters to make it format nicely).

Comment: -1 for a terrible question title. And for *screenshots* of code!

Comment: How can we tell you how to write what you want, if you don't tell us what you want? What is the behavior you want to produce?

Comment: The only thing we can tell you right now is that you can't put an `assign` statement inside a procedural block. If you want to change the value of something inside a procedural block, define it as a reg, and change its value with `=` or `<=`.

Comment: Shall I upload an upside-down photograph of the answer?

Comment: The Photon, thankyou so much for your help. But still I had errors when I had not used the "assign" word.

Comment: Did you define `sel` as a wire or a reg? You need to include all the relevant code if you want our help.

Comment: Also, the errors are indexed by line number. Please include line numbers in the listing so we can tell what error goes to what line.

Comment: i define all my control signals as "input" like, I am going to uplaod it since i am in the terminal now

Comment: You can't assign to inputs. They are coming in from somewhere else.

Comment: what do you mean, so I should declare all the control signals i have made as outputs

Comment: You should declare all the nets you are going to assign values to as wires or reg's. Whether they're outputs or not depends on whether you need to expose those nets to other modules.

Comment: we have two files, am290.v has inputs, but we are editing controller.v where we will map its control signals to Am290.v as ".reg_wr(reg_wr) ". The "reg_wr" is declared as a wire in Am290.v and as an output in controller.v, so that what I should do for all signals? Its quite confusing given things like "cin" were declared as inputs in AM290.v

Comment: @user124627, each name is local to its module. So one net could be a reg output from module1, and be hooked up to a wire net in module0 (which is where module1 is instantiated). If it's confusing, you could change the name of the net in one or the other modules.

Comment: Just like in C you might have a variable named `foo` in one function, and use it as an argument to another function. And in the called function, that (logical) variable could still be called `foo`, or it could be called something completely different like `number_of_turtles`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the error message:

> A net is not a legal lvalue in this context

- Procedural blocks can only assign registers types (Verilog:`reg`,SystemVerilog:`logic`/`bit`/`reg`). The assignment cannot be done to a input either
- Combinational logic should have blocking assignments (`=`) only, not non-blocking (`<=`)
- You should not used procedural continuous assignments (`assign` inside a procedural block)
- Every assigned bit must have an assignment for each condition. Otherwise a latch is inferred. An easy strategy is to assign default values to all registers at the top of a procedural block, the remaining code overrides the default.

Other Guidelines:

- Bit expatiation is not necessary:
- `i[5]==1 && i[4]==0 && i[3]==1` --> `i[5:3]==3'b101`
- Use auto sensitivity list for combination `always @*` (or SystemVerilog's `always_comb`)
- Long nested else-if comparing the same values bits can use a case statements

```
always_comb begin
  /* default assignments: e.g: cin='1; op='0; */
  case(i[5:3])
    3'b000 : begin /*S+R code*/ end
    3'b001 : begin /*S-R code*/ end
    3'b010 : begin /*R-S code*/ end
    // ... Other conditions ...
  endcase
end
```

Comment: this is very helpful, let me get down to code now

Comment: i keep getting the error for each line starting from always_comb. ... expecting a left parenthesis ('(') [12.1.2][7.1(IEEE)]... is always_comb really verilog or system verilog

Comment: `always_comb` is SysteVerilog, for Verilog use `always @*` NB: Verilog was merged into SystemVerilog in 2009.

Comment: @user124627, you tagged the question with "verilog" and "system-verilog", therefore I gave a SystemVerilog code example. I did state that `always @*` is the Verilog an equivalent of SystemVerilog's `always_comb`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't put an assign statement inside a procedural block.
2. You can't assign a value to an input net.

If you want to change the value of something inside a procedural block, define it as a reg, and change its value with = or <=.

For example

```
module test(input clk);
reg x;
always @(posedge clk) begin
     x <= ~x;
end
endmodule;
```